# Jupyter notebook: let a user inputs a drawing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, user-input

Simple question but I'm not able to find something out there...

Is there a simple and user friendly tool that can be used within a `jupyter-notebook` to let the user draw something in black on a white space (let say of size (x,y) pixels) after running a cell?

The drawing has to be returned (or even temporarily saved) as an array/image which can then be used by `numpy` for example.

Comment: Maybe `holoviews` lib can be twisted to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do that using `PIL` and `tkinter` libraries, like:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image, ImageDraw
import PIL
from tkinter import *

width = 200  # canvas width
height = 200 # canvas height
center = height//2
white = (255, 255, 255) # canvas back

def save():
    # save image to hard drive
    filename = "user_input.jpg"
    output_image.save(filename)

def paint(event):
    x1, y1 = (event.x - 1), (event.y - 1)
    x2, y2 = (event.x + 1), (event.y + 1)
    canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="black",width=5)
    draw.line([x1, y1, x2, y2],fill="black",width=5)

master = Tk()

# create a tkinter canvas to draw on
canvas = Canvas(master, width=width, height=height, bg='white')
canvas.pack()

# create an empty PIL image and draw object to draw on
output_image = PIL.Image.new("RGB", (width, height), white)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(output_image)
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", paint)

# add a button to save the image
button=Button(text="save",command=save)
button.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

You can modify the `save` function to read the image using `PIL` and `numpy` to have it as an `numpy` array. 
hope this helps!

Comment: Nice, it helped, yes. But if drawn too fast, a line appears dotted, which I do not want. I also fixed some little bugs and export the image using black and white mode as I don't need the 3 channels (I added the `PIL.image.new()` documentation URL in the code for all available modes).

Comment: yes, i've noticed the same issue when writing the code, I couldn't figure a way to change that, the only solution I could figure so far was moving the mouse slowly when drawing, please keep me informed if you find any @s.k

Comment: Should this work in notebook running in the cloud?   I get `TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`

Answer (score 2):

Try [ipycanvas](https://ipycanvas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with interactive drawing mode.
It actually has a demo notebook with interactive drawing that could be easily modified to do exactly what you want. It also has numpy support.

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion on jupyterlab's github page on this issue: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/9194. Apparently, it is planned to add Excalidraw at some point and until then, https://github.com/nicknytko/notebook-drawing was recommended.